# Check if file has been loaded using .load()

Tags: jquery, load

How would I check if file has been loaded in a div, and if not, try again (reload it)

I'm using .load() and fancybox to load the file in.

```
  $('a.button-1').click(function(){

       $('#data').load('form1.html');

});

 $('a.button-2').click(function(){

       $('#data').load('form2.html');

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like what is in the jquery docs for `load`:

```
$("div").load("/test.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqMWL/

Although I would be careful with just continuously retrying.

Comment: I think you may be right about load, but I'm going to check the source. Everybody always raves about the jQuery documentation but I find it to be woefully erratic in the completeness of the API specifications. *edit* - yup you're definitely right!

Comment: Just to follow-up a now deleted discussion, trying to call `.fail` on `.load`:  "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fail'"  http://jsfiddle.net/fqMWL/1